# Magento 2 - How to add,save,display custom Field in Product Edit form using UiComponent?

Tags: magento2, product, forms, magento2.2.2, product-edit

Hi I want to add a custom field in **Product** **add/Edit form** using **UiComponent** and want to **save its value** and **displayed back to form as well**

I have read a couple of threads for this - but not getting the exact solution

I have added custom field using uicomponent in **product_form.xml** file below is the code  :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">   
<modal name="advanced_inventory_modal">  
     <fieldset name="manage_note">
         <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">        
             <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                 <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Manage Note</item>
                 <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string"/>
                 <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                 <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                 <item name="opened" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
             </item>
         </argument>
         <field name="note">
             <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                 <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                     <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Notes</item>
                     <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">textarea</item>
                     <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">quantity_and_stock_status.note</item>
                     <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                     <item name="scopeLabel" xsi:type="string">[GLOBAL]</item>
                 </item>
             </argument>
         </field>          
     </fieldset>
     <fieldset name="stock_data">
         <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
             <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                 <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Stock Configuration</item>
                 <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string"/>
                 <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">100</item>
                 <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
             </item>
         </argument>
     </fieldset>   
</modal>
</form>
```

Custom Field is added successfully, but its value is not getting saved ? due to that its value is not displayed in edit form as well.

so what is the best approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I  have resolved this issue by myself, below is the way i have resolved it.

I have created Observer which calls after product save event.

so below is the **events.xml** file below is the code :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_product_save_after">
        <observer name="Vendor_Module::save_custom_data" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\AfterProductSave"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

Below is my Observer **AfterProductSave code** :

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class AfterProductSave implements ObserverInterface
{

    /**
     * Custom factory
     *
     * @var \Vendor\ModuleName\Model\CustomProductsFactory
     */
    protected $_CustomProductsFactory;

    /**
     * Http Request
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http
     */
    protected $request;
    
    
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Group\Collection $customerGroup
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Vendor\ModuleName\Model\CustomProductsFactory $customProductsFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_CustomProductsFactory = $CustomProductsFactory;
        $this->request = $request;
    }
    
    
    /**
     *
     *  @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getProduct();
        
        if ((!empty($product)))) {
            $productId = $product->getId();
            $requestId = $this->request->getParam('id');
            $productName =  $product->getName();
            $customFieldSetData = serialize($product->getCustomFieldSet());
            if ($productId) {
                $this->saveCustomProductData($requestId,$productId,$customFieldSetData);
            }
        }
    }
    

    public function saveCustomProductData($requestId,$productId,$customFieldSetData)
    {
        
        $model = $this->_CustomProductsFactory->create();
        
        if (empty($requestId)) {
            $data = ['custom_data'=>$customFieldSetData,'product_id'=>$productId];
        } else {
            //load model
            $model->load($productId, 'product_id');
            $data = ['custom_data'=>$customFieldSetData,'product_id'=>$productId]];
        }
        
        $model->addData($data);
        
        $model->save();
    }
}
```

**Updated Date:- 10th Aug, 2021**

***if you can't show value of custom field at Edit Page then try below code***

> Create di.xml file at Vendor/ModuleName/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="customTab" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">
                        Vendor\ModuleName\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\CustomField
                    </item>
                    <!-- <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">70</item> -->
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

> then create **CustomField.php** file at
> Vendor\ModuleName\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Locator\LocatorInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AbstractModifier;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Fieldset;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Field;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Select;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\DataType\Text;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Input;

class CustomField extends AbstractModifier
{
    private $locator;
    
    public function __construct(
        LocatorInterface $locator
    ) {
        $this->locator = $locator;
    }

    public function modifyData(array $data)
    {
        $product   = $this->locator->getProduct();
        $productId = $product->getId();
        $custom_test = $product->getCustom_test(); //this is my custom field

        $data = array_replace_recursive(
            $data, [
                $productId => [
                    'product' => [
                        'custom_test' => $custom_test,
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ); 
        //Note:- Array Depends on your datascrope string value which one you defined at product_form.xml UI component file...
       //in my case, I defined <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data.product</item> like this in UI component .xml file that's why I use that array format, you have to change according to your case
        return $data;
    }

    public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
    {
        return $meta;
    }
}
```

In above Modifier File CustomField.php there are two functions,

1st one **modifyData()** - adding data when the product edit page is loaded.

2nd one **modifyMeta()** – creating field, fieldset. it is used for create custom field.
but it's not necessary to use modifyMeta() for create Custom field, Fieldset in form, If you are using Magento 2 Or above Version then you can add/create field, fieldset using .xml file UI Component

Comment: do i need to create a 'custom_data' field in the database or it will save automatically? actually i want to add new field for custom images admin can upload multiple images from the product edit page.

Comment: Please update full code along with creating custom field, i need to create one custom field with name actual_qty, how can i do that?

Comment: I need to create one custom field with name actual_qty and same like you save and retrieve value during edit, how can i do that?  please provide me full code, thanks

Comment: how to move that custom field into product detail section?